# Fixed memory principle in fractional calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I am trying to read [this paper](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20020024453_2002030194.pdf) and have a certain doubt. On page 8 the author comments that

> First of all, there is a fundamental problem associated with all
>   fractional differential operators (not only the Caputo version that we
>   look at here): In contrast to differential operators of integer order,
>   fractional derivatives are not local operators. As a matter of fact,
>   this property is highly desirable from the physical point of view
>   because it allows us to model phenomena with memory effects. But when
>   it comes to numerical work we find that this non-locality leads to a
>   significantly higher computational effort: The arithmetic complexity
>   of our algorithm with step size h is $O(h^{-2})$, whereas a comparable
>   algorithm for an integer-order initial value problem (thus involving a
>   local operator) would only give rise to a $O(h^{-1})$ complexity. A
>   number of ways have been suggested to overcome this difficulty. The
>   first idea seems to have been the fixed memory principle of
>   Podlubny[31].

What I understand from this is that since fractional differential operators have two terminal points within which they are evaluated so the derivative is not evaluated at a point. In that sense it is not local. The fixed memory principle in [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=K5FdXohLto0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=fractional%20differential%20equations&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8oAaUYGRGMuGrAfe6IG4CQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA) is not clear to me. I only found a reference to a short memory principle and even that wasn't clear. Can someone please explain this principle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are less involved if you use the Grunwald-Letnikov derivative. You can fix a criterion to "cut" the summation. Besides this derivative does not have the problems of the others RL or C. I used the short memory principle in a paper about the two-sided derivative. I can send it to you. Send me a mail.

mdo@fct.unl.pt